# Custom routing ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

So I want to get my URLs to look something similar to this:

`example.com`, `example.com/contact`, `example.com/sign-up`, `example.com/account`

Instead of the default MVC way which would look like:

`example.com`, `example.com/Home/Contact`, `example.com/Account/SignUp`, `example.com/Account/Account`

All `HomeController` views work fine, but my `AccountController` doesn't.

When going to `example.com/account` I get an error saying:

> The resource cannot be found.

This is my `RouteConfig`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Account",
        url: "{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Account", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And because I wanted to display the `Account/SignUp` view as `/sign-up` I added some custom code in the `AccountController`.

```
// GET: Account
public ActionResult Account()
{
    return View();
}

// GET: Sign Up
[ActionName("Sign-Up")]
public ActionResult SignUp()
{
    return View("SignUp");
}
```

Both formats `/account` or `/account/account` give me the same error from earlier.
However `/about`, `/contact`, etc. does not.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

P.S This is my folder structure:

```
> Views
-> Account
--> Account.cshtml
--> SignUp.cshtml
-> Home
--> About.cshtml
--> Contact.cshtml
--> Index.cshtml
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your route to something like this? url: "/Account/{action}/{id}",

Comment: @LukeAlderton that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route setup would need to be more explicit.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Account",
        url: "account/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Account", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Yeah I realised I have to have it like `account/sign-up` rather than just `sign-up`. Which is a bit unfortunate but I could easily add it the `HomeController` if that's how I really wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe custom route should be before default route

Comment: That sets the home page to be the `Account` page unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you should look here for more informations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Comment: This is from Microsoft documentation:
The order of the routes that you add to the route table is important. Our new custom  route is added before the existing Default route. If you reversed the order, then the Default route always will get called instead of the custom route.

Answer (score 0):

Add RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Add AccountController.cs as an attribute to the SignUp method

```
[Route("Sign-Up")]
```

Finally:

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
[Route("Sign-Up")]
public ActionResult SignUp()
{
  ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

  return View();
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcwFI.jpg)